# Prove that $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \leq 3$, then $2^n< 3n+2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

Prove that $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \leq 3$, then $2^n< 3n+2$

I need to prove this sentence is true. In this problem, I believe I have to use the exhaustion demo technique. Because there is a specific number of cases, in this case between natural $0$ and $3$.
I've tried to solve it, I came to a conclusion, and apparently it's correct. But I would like someone to look at the strategy used for the resolution and if I am correct about my conclusion.

**My resolution method:**

1º Create a table with possible values for $n$ and compare the sentence

$$
\begin{array}{c c l}
n & 2^n < 3n + 2 & \text{result}\\ \hline
0 & 1 < 2 & \text{true}\\
1 & 2 < 5 & \text{true}\\
2 & 4 < 8 & \text{true}\\
3 & 8 < 11 & \text{true}
\end{array}
$$

Thus, by exhaustion, it is possible to prove that the theorem is true. For any and all $n \geq 0$ and $\leq 3$, it will always be less than $2^n < 3n+2$.

Is this argument valid as an answer?

Comment: This is a perfectly valid argument. (As a bonus, you can use the same method to prove your misprint, $2n<3n+2$.)

Answer (score 1):

Although your statement (to be proven) is self-explanatory, a way of thinking is given below, which can help to solve such a task in general:

We have $2^n<3n+2$, which I can rewrite as $2^n-11<3n-9$.

Your condition $n\le3$ is equal to $n-3\le0$ and respectively to $3n-9\le0$ leading to:

$$2^n-11<3n-9\le0$$

Indeed the largest possible $n$ that satisfies $2^n-11\le0$ is $3$.